# script to ping every second for a set time, pause for a set time, then repeat

Tags: macos, ping

Edit: I concluded this question was posted in the wrong place. I [posted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/454568/255997) in a Mac OS specific forum and got an answer right away.

I've found that I will sometimes have internet connectivity problems that last about 4 seconds, return to normal for about 15 seconds, and then happen again. From what I can tell so far, the problem can last 5 to 7 hours at a time. I want to get a better understanding of it so I can communicate it to my internet service provider.

So far, I've been using:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; done
```

importantly, this has a timestamp included with a ping every second. I have a script to plot the results using the timestamp. But since the problem may only happen 2 or 3 times a week, it collects a lot of unnecessary data that I then have to sort through.

What I would like is to ping every second for a set time (say 5-10 minutes) and then pause for a set time (again, say 5-10 minutes).  I know there is a `sleep` command and I've tried to use it; but I haven't been able to reach my goal yet.

Comment: Why not simply mark a start time (via the `date` command), then run a continuous ping?  `ping` defaults to one packet per second, and the missing packets (say, number 259) will tell you how many seconds into the test the packet was dropped.  This will give you the advantage of a continuous timeline, and is certainly a lot simpler to implement.  Perhaps: '( date; ping -c 1000 8.8.8.8 ) > test-output.txt 2>&1` (assuming `bash`).

Comment: I was able to get this to work, producing a file which has 1 ping every second. The problem is that when things are normal this produces way more datapoints than I need. Also when you plot that many points in a spreadsheet it's very troublesome. If I can achieve my goal of only collecting data every 5 minutes or so that would dramatically reduce the number of points and make assessing my internet connectivity problem more manageable.

Comment: It still seems like you're re-inventing the wheel.  A `cron` job could run your test every X minutes, and the `-c` parameter to `ping` in your test script will control the number of pings per test.  I'd also suggest adding a date stamp to the output file, such as `(date; ping -c 200) > test-output.$(date +%Y%m%d).txt`.  200 pings every five minutes ought to be enough for an ISP technician to run with.

Comment: Duh... a better filename would use `$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)` so that the filename shows when the sample was taken.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the interval and collection attributes for `ping`. The documentation (`man ping`) has plenty of information, but you might want to start with this.

```
#!/bin/sh
target=1.1.1.1     # Ping target
delay=$((60*5))    # Seconds (5 minutes)

while :
do
    # Linux (GNU)
    # ping -4 -q -n -c3 -i1 -w4 "$target" >/dev/null 2>&1 && st=ok || st=error
    # Mac (OSX)
    ping -q -n -c3 -i1 -t4 "$target" >/dev/null 2>&1 && st=ok || st=error
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(date)" "$st"
    sleep "$delay"
done
```

Put this in a file such as `pingit`, and make the script executable with `chmod a+x pingit`. Then you can run it as `./pingit`.

It sends three consecutive pings every five minutes. If any succeed it's considered "ok" otherwise it's an "error".

Another option is to remove the `while … do` ... `done` loop construction and call the remainder of the script from `cron` every *N* minutes.

Comment: I tested your code but it didn't work for me. It gives this as an error: "ping: invalid option --4"     I probably should have mentioned I'm running Terminal on Mac OS. As I said, I don't know much about scripts in Terminal.

Comment: What I want is something like this:  << ping 8.8.8.8 | while read line; do echo `date` - $line; sleep 600; done >> which gives 1 ping every 10 minutes.  It's just that I want, say, 200 pings every 10min instead of just 1

Comment: I was getting all sorts of errors due to the #'s, and eventually simplified it to this: while :
do
    ping -q -n -c3 -i1 -t4 1.1.1.1 2>&1 && st=ok || st=error
    printf "%s - %s\n" "$(date)" "$st"
    sleep 60
done          which did work, giving 4 pings every 60s.  So that's the closest I've gotten to my goal.  The output is messy, but I could make it work.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm simply pasting exactly what you wrote into a new Terminal window.  I'm running the latest Max OS (Mac OS 13.2) on an M1 MacAir. I apologize for knowing very little about Terminal.

Comment: @TonyM I've added instructions on creating this as a script, so it will work regardless of your shell. Please try this now

Comment: thanks for all your help, but unfortunately this is still not working for me. The chmod part worked fine, but then when attempting to execute I get "zsh: exec format error: ./pingit" I looked up this error and one site said "That's a 32-bit executable. It won't work on a modern version of macOS." -- Whether that's the problem, I really don't know. I didn't realize my question was so OS specific, and I'm beginning to think I may be in the wrong forum for this question...

Comment: @TonyM double check the very first line of the script. It should be exactly `#!/bin/sh` - nothing more, nothing less

Comment: I did the check and it was exactly as you wrote. Please see my edit to the original question: I decided I posted to a Mac OS-specific area and got an answer right away.

Comment: @TonyM well I have no idea what you and I are doing differently. I'm typing this on my Mac having retested exactly the instructions I gave in the question. (You didn't create the script on a Windows machine and copy it across, did you...?)